# Why does Minecraft get stuck when javaw.exe reaches 757.356kb of memory use?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Why does Minecraft get stuck when javaw.exe reaches 757.356kb of memory use.

Can I remove this limit or is there anything else I can do to solve the problem?

Comment: The game is still in beta so its more than likely just a bug. Check out the Minecraft community maybe log into IRC and ask. http://www.minecraft.net/community.jsp

Answer (score 19):

New answer, so everyone can follow the steps:

1. Open up a notepad.
2. Type the following:

   `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -jar "C:\minecraft.jar"`
3. File -> Save as. Choose All file types, and save it like: `C:\minecraft.bat`
4. Get minecraft's "linux version" at http://minecraft.net. Save it to `C:\minecraft.jar`  [This step is not necessary for jre7 running on Windows 7, you can point the script to minecraft.exe]
5. *You can skip this step if you are running 32 bit windows!* Get a 64-bit Java runtime. This wouldn't be a neccessary step, but since Minecraft is a resource hog, you may want to squeeze out all the juice from your computer. You can find the 64-bit version [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
6. Double-Click the minecraft.bat file.

What does the .bat file do?

- The first part tells Windows, when you double-click the .bat, it should launch Java runtime
- The second part is the `-Xmx` and `-Xms` part. These are settings for the heap size. Set these according how much memory you have. [Explanation for this Heap stuff.](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp)
- The last part `-jar C:\...` is an argument too, telling Java where it can find the Minecraft.jar launcher.

(Also, check the `C:\minecraft.jar`, `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe` paths. These things may vary.)

---

**A little extra, performance improvement:** (The argument part works only on Windows!)
Add the following arguments to the .bat file:
`"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=false  -Dsun.java2d.d3d=true -Dsun.java2d.opengl=false -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -jar "C:\minecraft.jar"`

This way, we tell Java it should use DirectX to draw. This helped me a lot.

**Another improvement can be achieved** (Cross-platform!) if you install [Java JRE7](http://download.java.net/jdk7/). It's in a beta state, but perfect for us, playing Minecraft. You only have to modify the .bat file, so it shows:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java`
instead of the
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java`
(Notice the number in the "jre".)

Comment: If you don't know how to do this, I'll get into the details, just comment on the answer.

Comment: You should explain your command-line a bit more, for those who aren't used to it. For example, you could explain which part of this command-line modify the memory use limitation...

Comment: Nice explanation!!! (By the way, i wasn't aware of the JRE7 beta...)

Comment: The informatiin is good, but why do you suggest storing things in the root of c:?

Comment: Since its just the launcher of minecraft and a single bat file.. about 2mb, that's the easiest way. :) (But, of course, you can put them anywhere, just remember to modify the .bat file to reflect your Minecraft launcher's path.)

Comment: Actually, you will probably see more memory used with the 64-bit jvm than the 32-bit JVM for equivalent heap sizes -- if memory usage is your largest concern, and your desired heap can be satisfied by a 32-bit JVM, you should stay on 32-bit.

Comment: That OpenGL thing is a bit weird. Isn't Minecraft OpenGL-based anyway? I'm confused.

Comment: Uncle: No, it uses a library for newbies. Java can draw stuff with both.